# populate list of list in java

Tags: java, list

I'm trying to fill a list of list `List<List<String>>` in Java, but when I print the elements, nothing appears!

my code:

```
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<>();
for (int z = 0; z < c.POSList.get("V").size(); z++) {
    temp.add(c.stemmer(c.POSList.get("V").get(z)).get(0));
    temp.addAll(c.ReturnListOFSynoums(c.stemmer(c.POSList.get("V").get(z)).get(0), ""));
    System.out.println(temp); // there are elements !
    verbsMatrix.add(temp);
    temp.clear();
}

for (int s = 0; s < verbsMatrix.size(); s++) {
    for (int r = 0; r < verbsMatrix.get(s).size(); r++) {
        System.out.print(verbsMatrix.get(s).get(r) + "  ");
    }
}
```

Comment: What makes you think anything ever got added to `verbsMatrix`?

Comment: My first comment is that this doesn't look like Java... Capitalised field names, direct field access for mutable types, collection looping using for loop... But temp.clear() is probably your problem.

Comment: @scotthunter .. verbsMatrix.add(temp);  !!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're clearing `temp` every time, this is the same instance you just added to `verbsMatrix` which you don't re-initialize.

Try declaring `temp` inside the for, and don't clear it.

Comment: Thanx man .. I have done it before but it was not works, but now it works  :ss